# How To Login on website? Password as value not accepted

Tags: vb.net, authentication, passwords

I've looked at many examples on how to log in to a website using vb. But somehow it keeps saying the password is incorrect.

Let me explain:
I'm trying to log in to this website using vb. I have managed to fill in the username and the password using

```
wb1.Document.GetElementById("Username").SetAttribute("Value", "myusername")
wb1.Document.GetElementById("Password").SetAttribute("Value", "mypassword")
```

I can see them being filled in, but upon clicking on the login button it says the password in incorrect. When I try to fill in the password by hand (username by program) and click the button it does work.
The difference between the two instances? When I do it manually the letters I type become dots. But when I do it via my program the letters do not change but remain letters. I think this is part of the problem, but I'm not entirely sure.

I've tried to change other items as well such as OuterHTML from the element Password. I could see which items were adjusted when I manually entered the password. And then I used those values. This didn't work. But then again, it was hard to see what exactly changed, so maybe I missed something.

One thing I noticed while doing to was when I manually entered the password Value was changed to "". Should I put my password in a different attribute? I'm guessing the password should be send encoded to the server?

This is the code for the password field on the website

```
<div class="jNiceInputWrapper jNiceSafari FieldPosition col2">
    <div class="jNiceInputInner">
        <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" class="jNiceInput" placeholder="Wachtwoord" onkeypress="return SubmitOnEnter(this,event)" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I really hope someone can help me with this problem. I've been working on it all day and just can't figure it out.

EDIT:
Thanks to Mr CoDeXeR I finally figured it out!
The code that solved the problem:

```
wb1.Document.All("Username").SetAttribute("value", "myusername")
wb1.Document.All("Password").SetAttribute("value", "mypassword")

Dim elements As HtmlElementCollection = (wb1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("Password"))
For Each element As HtmlElement In elements
     element.InnerText = "mypassword"
Next
```

Removing either the setattribute value or the innertext will lead to failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, don't use GetElementsByID, use Document.All instead. You want to pass the element's name attribute value to all, you may be just missing some of them...

```
 wB1.Document.All("Username").SetAttribute("value", Username)
 wB1.Document.All("Password").SetAttribute("value", Password)
```

Let me know how this works out for you

EDIT

Upon looking at this more, we can't use the ways we tried since it's a masked input. Instead we can loop through the document and set the inner text of that element...

```
  ' Loop through elements until the element is found
    Dim elements As HtmlElementCollection = wB1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("Password")
    For Each element As HtmlElement In elements
        element.InnerText = "your password"
    Next
```

Comment: OMG! It worked 0o. With a few adjustments tho.
Thanks so much!! I'll edit my original post with the code I used.